# Keeping track of pointers generated in recursion

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, memory, memory-leaks

I have a situation where it is unclear when a pointer should be discarded. This is due to the class using recursion with different methods being called based on the input.
Below I have recreated a very crude example of this situation. In my code that I'm writing instead of `Data*` as the return for the recursion, I used a `typedef boost::variant` which has a mix of pointers and standard types, making it even harder to keep track of which are pointers that need to be freed up.

```
struct Data {
    int a = 2;
    Data(int ca) {
        a = ca;
    }

};


class MemoryLeakCentral {
public:

      MemoryLeakCentral(int a) {
           doStuff(a);
      }

      ~MemoryLeakCentral() {
           /*    delete all pointers  */
       }

      Data* createPointer(int a) {
          Data* data = new Data(a);
          return data;
      }   

private:
    Data* doStuff(int a) {
         Data* data = createPointer(5);
         /*
             do stuff with "data"
             e.g. 

             if(data->a == ...) {
                data->a = ...
                return doMoreStuff(data)
             }
             else if(...)
             else if(...) etc
         */
         return data;
     }


     Data* doMoreStuff(Data* data) {
         /*
             do stuff with "data"

             if(data->a == ...) {
                data->a = ...
                return doMoreStuff(data)
             }
             else if(...)
             else if(...) etc
         */
         return data;
     }

    ...
    //more Data* returning functions

};
```

In the code above I'm trying to create the perception that the recursion is deep and complicated.

My question is: what is the best way of getting the class `MemoryLeakCentral` to delete all the pointers that it generates once it hits the destructor. 
One idea I had was to store all the pointers created at `createPointer` in a vector then once the `~MemoryLeakCentral` is called, loop through the vector and delete all the pointers.

Are there any better solutions then this? I know the point where a pointer is created, but can't easily determine where it is destroyed due to the complex recursion that takes place.

Comment: There is one very easy way to keep track of pointers: *don't do manual memory management*.  Don't use `new`. This way everything becomes simpler. If you need to use pointers for some reason, use smart pointers. And *don't use `new`*.

Comment: I second @Yksisarvinen. A smart pointer will ensure proper destruction. If you must use pointers, at the very least you should define clearly what do you expect the lifetime of a pointer to be - the same recursion level it was made?

Comment: @kabanus thanks for the input guys. I was under the impression that using pointers instead of objects is more efficient. For this program I care a lot about efficiency. Would using pointers have much of a impact on speed considering that the "Data" object I'm using has a lot of data?

Comment: @Tom Creating an object takes up the same memory. The difference might be if you are out of stack memory, then perhaps dynamic allocation makes sense. If the stack is sufficient, then using real objects and passing references would be just as efficient.